# jQuery alternate row colors across multiple tables

Tags: jquery, css

I am noticing an issue with alternating row colors strictly using jquery.
You can look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dkindler/WgRY5/1/) for an example of what I will describe.

I am using CSS3 to control striping on tables which works as expected across multiple tables.

```
.table-zebra tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td {background-color: lightgrey;}
```

Every even row is striped with a light grey.  The count starts from the first row.

For browsers that do not support CSS3 I use jquery to mimic this: (.table-striped used for this example to show difference in fiddle)

```
  $(".table-striped tr:odd").css("background-color", 'lightgrey');
```

When I have multiple tables with odd number of rows jquery will continue the count from the previous table and this alternates the rows incorrectly.

Besides using $.each is there a simpler way to handle this in jquery?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the `:odd` is applied across all the `<TR>`s and therefore you get the behaviour you describe. I don't think there is any way to change that and make the `:odd` relative to the current `.table-striped` except by using `.each()`.

For this specific case though there is a workaround with `:nth-child`:

```
$(".table-striped tr:nth-child(:odd)").css("background-color", 'lightgrey');
```

although that applies if a particular `<TR>` is an odd child of its immediate parent and therefore might do the wrong thing if your `<TABLE>`s contain multiple `<TBODY>`s.

Comment: `odd` is not a pseudo-class, `:odd` is a jQuery selector, so there shouldn't be a `:` for the `odd` when using `:nth-child`. I'd edit but it's a single char so it won't let me.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
tr.even td {
    background-color: green;
}
tr.odd td {
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

JS:

```
 $('.table-striped > tbody').each(function () {
     $('tr:odd', this).addClass('odd').removeClass('even');
     $('tr:even', this).addClass('even').removeClass('odd');
 });
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/WCBBc/)