# jQuery: Zebra striped table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have two table on page and I am trying to give it zebra strip effect. It works fines but for second `table` `tr` taking count from first table. Due to this even `tr` become the first `tr`.

Example of my work
http://jsfiddle.net/A9wpe/1/

code I am using for this is below:

```
$('table tr:even:not(:first)').css('background-color','#ededed');
```

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15789526/jquery-alternate-row-colors-across-multiple-tables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could always iterate through each table, acting on each independently:

```
$('table').each(function(){$(this).find('tr:even').css('background-color','#ededed')});
```

Or, if your users have recent browsers, you'd do this in CSS:

```
table tr:nth-child(even) {background-color: #ededed;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use jQuery for this. Use CSS instead

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/5DnLW/)

```
.subPro-data tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color : #ededed;
}
```

---

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fresheyeball/xz4Xs/)
With jQuery for old IE

```
.subPro-data tr.even{
    background-color : #ededed;
}
```

and

```
$('.subPro-data tr:even').addClass('even');
```

---

Point is you want to avoid selectors like this `$('table#{tableID1} tr:even:not(:first), table#{tableID2} tr:even:not(:first)')`. Its a nightmare of inefficiency, and ultimately its so complicated only because you are using the following command: `.css('background-color','#ededed');`

Using `.css` adds those styles to the inline `style` attribute on the dom element. http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp inline styles override almost all css rules. What you should be doing is just adding a class instead. That way the background color lives in a css rule and will naturally be in the right location in the css cascade.

This also means you can use a simple and sane selector like this `$('.subPro-data tr:even')`.

Comment: I can use css but I need IE7 support too.

Comment: Sorry I hadn't time to comment at the time. I downvoted because the OP asked for a jQuery solution (for which he might have had valid reasons, like browser support) and you provided a CSS one, further suggesting he shouldn't do what he was asking for. With your edits, I removed the downvote.

Comment: FYI, a JS/jQuery solution is desirable if some of the rows are hidden.  As of this moment, there is no general widely-supported method of zebra striping using pure CSS when rows are hidden using `display:none`.

Comment: Update: Great news - looks like there *are* some non-JS solutions for when rows are hidden!  http://christianheilmann.com/2013/12/12/zebra-tables-using-nth-child-and-hidden-rows/

Answer (score 1):

Give *id* for both table and use jQuery below:

```
$('table#{tableID1} tr:even:not(:first), table#{tableID2} tr:even:not(:first)').css('background-color','#ededed');
```

Replace table *id* with `{tableID1}` and `{tableID2}`. See JSFiddle [example](http://jsfiddle.net/rakeshurgreat/KTzZf/).

Answer (score 0):

```
$('table').each(function(index, value) { $(value).find('tr:even:not(:first)').css('background-color','#ededed');});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter rows using `:not(:first)` and then apply `nth-child(odd)` rule.
check [DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/A9wpe/9/)

`$('table tr:not(:first):nth-child(odd)').css('background-color','#ededed');`